# How to remove columns after any row has a NaN value in Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

### Toy example code

Let's say I have following `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[11,21,31], "B":[12,22,32], "C":[np.nan,23,33], "D":[np.nan,24,34], "E":[15,25,35]})
```

Which would return:

```
>>> df
    A   B     C     D   E
0  11  12   NaN   NaN  15
1  21  22  23.0  24.0  25
2  31  32  33.0  34.0  35
```

### Remove all columns with `nan` values

I know how to remove all the columns which have any row with a `nan` value like this:

```
out1 = df.dropna(axis=1, how="any")
```

Which returns:

```
>>> out1
    A   B   E
0  11  12  15
1  21  22  25
2  31  32  35
```

### Expected output

However what I expect is to remove all columns after a `nan` value is found. In the toy example code the expected output would be:

```
    A   B
0  11  12
1  21  22
2  31  32
```

### Question

How can I remove all columns after a `nan` is found within any row in a `pandas` `DataFrame` ?

Comment: Your question asks how to remove columns **after** a `nan`, so column `C` should remain (unless the question is how to remove columns with a `NaN` and the column immediately after it).

Comment: Maybe I should refrase. The expected output is what I’m looking for. Once a nan is found within a column that column and the remaining ones after that one should be dropped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do:

1. check every element for being null/not null
2. cumulative sum every row across the columns
3. check `any` for every column, across the rows
4. use that result as an indexer:

```py
df.loc[:, ~df.isna().cumsum(axis=1).any(axis=0)]
```

Give me:

```
    A   B
0  11  12
1  21  22
2  31  32
```

Comment: This is a really elegant and simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

I could find a way as follows to get the expected output:

```
colFirstNaN = df.isna().any(axis=0).idxmax() # Find column that has first NaN element in any row
indexColLastValue = df.columns.tolist().index(colFirstNaN) -1
ColLastValue = df.columns[indexColLastValue]
out2 = df.loc[:, :ColLastValue]
```

And the output would be then:

```
>>> out2
    A   B
0  11  12
1  21  22
2  31  32
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a more elegant way. But this solution was what I have found so far.

Comment: `df.iloc[:, :colFirstNaN]`?

Comment: @Dan if I use that code I get `TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [C] of <type 'str'>`